# Adobe Flash upgrade

Tags: updates

Have to update Adobe Flash in order to play games on line.Tried to download it from website but get a box that asks me to choose an app to open it with,but I have no idea which one I should use. I know you can also use terminal,but I have never used it and don't know the proper commands. Could someone please point me in the right direction so I can get it working again.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** via Adobe website

1. Go here: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
2. In the drop-down lists, select `Linux 64 bit` and `FP 32 for Ubuntu (apt)`.
3. Click `Next` and follow on-screen instructions.

**Option 2:** via Terminal

Launch Terminal and execute the following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt install adobe-flashplugin browser-plugin-freshplayer-pepperflash`

Then restart your browser and go to http://isflashinstalled.com to check if Flash plugin is working.